# Dygraph Variable in Data Array

Tags: javascript, dygraphs, qliksense

I am a beginner in javascript and just have two questions regarding the Dygraph javascript library.
I am making a Qlik Sense extension and I am having problems giving data to Dygraph.

```
for (var r = 0; r < hc.qDataPages[0].qMatrix.length; r++) {
        data += '[';
                    for (var c = 0; c < hc.qDataPages[0].qMatrix[r].length; c++) {
                      data += hc.qDataPages[0].qMatrix[r][c].qText += ',';
                    }
        data += '],';
      }

g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
                      [ 
                        data 
                      ],
                      {
                        labels: [ dimensions, measures ]

                      }
                     );
```

When I run this code, I get this error

```
Mismatch between number of labels ("OrderDate", ,"Count(Quantity)", ) and number of columns in array (1497)
```

My other question is how do I make the x axis display as dates rather than weird numbers.

```
g.updateOptions({

                axes: {
                    x: {
                        axisLabelFormatter: function(x) {
                            return x;
                        }
                       },
                    y: {
                        axisLabelFormatter: function(y) {
                            return y;
                        }
                       } 
                      }                
            });
```

Regards,
Shobokshy